# Which one is better in between O(log n) and O(log n^2)?

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

This is a Question that my (Data Structure)course teacher did in a Class Test. What would be the proper answer here? Since log n^2 =2 log n , as far as I know in a time complexity it could be written as O(log n) since constant multipliers cancels out. Then is one better than the other in any specific way?

Answer (score 1):

Asymptotically they are the same.

Your reasoning is right, O(log n^2) can be simplified to O(log n) and obviously they are equals.

It's like you have two algorithms that works on an array, the first is O(n) and the second is O(2n).
If you look to the number of performed operation, the second performs double the operation of the first but this is not important for the Asymptotic notation.
They are in the same order that is O(n).

In your specific example the order is O(log n) and they can be considered the same.

Answer (score 0):

I would agree with you that any O(log(x^k)) is O(log(x)). The computational complexity scales the same.